# Why is $f$ a homomorphism in this proof?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

[Here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Schur%27s_Lemma_(Representation_Theory)) a proof of Schur's lemma for representations is given. The proof begins by letting $f:V\to V'$ be a '[homomorphism of $G$-modules](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:G-Module_Homomorphism)', but clicking on that link, I don't see how you can conclude that $f$ is a homomorphism. In fact, multiplication on $V$ and $W$ do not seem to be defined there.

Comment: You're not *concluding* that $f$ is a homomorphism -- you're *assuming* it. That's the hypothesis of the lemma.

Comment: That isn't a conclusion, it's an assumption.

Comment: Do you mean a multiplication of two elements of $V$?  That has nothing to do with *module homomorphisms*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conclude that $f$ is a homomorphism (of vectorspaces) as the definition of a homomorphism of $G$-modules includes the assumption that $f$ is a linear map a.k.a. a homomorphism (of vertorspaces).